# Perl: Use dynamically-scoped variable inside subroutine under "use strict"

Tags: perl

Suppose I have the subroutine `printvar` which I call from another subroutine `main`. I have the flexibility of declaring `$var` to be lexically-scoped using

```
my $var;

sub printvar {
  print "var is: $var";
}

sub main {
  $var = 5.0;
  printvar();
}

main();
```

or dynamically-scoped using

```
sub printvar {
  print "var is: $var";
}

sub main {
  local $var = 5.0;
  printvar();
}

main();
```

But when `use strict` is in effect, the second example fails at compile-time with two messages (one in `printvar` and the other in `main`):

```
Global symbol "$var" requires explicit package name
```

If I want to use `$var` as a global within `printvar`, rather than passing it as an argument, and I want `printvar` to not care which scope `$var` comes from, is there a way to do this under `use strict`?

### In response to @mockinterface's answer:

Using `our`, I've modified the second example as such:

```
sub printvar {
  our $var;
  print "var is: $var";
}

sub main {
  our $var = 5;
  {
    local $var = 10;
    printvar();
  }
  printvar();
}
```

I see the output

```
var is: 10
var is: 5
```

So it looks like `our $var` within `printvar` is the key here.

Comment: I tried using your sample, I am not getting an error http://ideone.com/cqrxqY

Comment: @nrathaus Yes, the first version is legal Perl. The question is about the second version.

Comment: where in the second sample did you define `$var`?

Comment: Why not just use a global and assign to it when needed?

This type of witchcraft just causes headaches..

Comment: @ZachLeighton yes, I was wondering if it's possible to avoid forward-declaring the global above the subroutine in which it is referenced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, in your scenario - with strict, you can only promote or explicitly retrieve the variable to/from global scope with `our`.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;

sub printvar {
  our $var;
  print "var is: $var";
}

sub main {
  our $var = 5.0;
  printvar();
}

&main();
```